# Identify 80's TV, Film or Book plot about the dead talking though the TV

Tags: story-identification

When I was but a small lad back in the 80's I saw a feature on a Saturday kids morning TV show.  It was about children in a house and spirits were talking to them through switched off TVs. Very poltergeist I know but this was a kids programme.  I think it was a book they were showcasing but why go to the trouble of making a video of kids and ghostly TVs to go with it? 
I've googled but I keep getting the film "White Noise" which was made about 20 years after what I saw.
This is driving me potty...

Comment: A few questions:  1) Was this animated or live action?  2) Could the spirits communicate through anything other than TVs?  3) What was the communication effect like?  That is, was the spirit's voice audible, or was the ghost shown on the TV, or something else?

Comment: It was live action, and I think that it may have been any electronics but I'm not too sure as TVs were quite prominent.

Comment: 3. The spirits talked but in that tropey "ghostyyyy" voice. Veeeery sloooow aaaand scaaaaaary.

Comment: Ok.  The original description sounded like a show I remember seeing in the early 90s, but after these updates, I'm pretty sure they're not the same.  Hopefully this extra info will help someone else.